# Need to fill blanks in one column with ascending dates of the month

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that creates daily reports in separate worksheets and at the end of the month I click a button that creates a monthly summary sheet from all of the individual daily sheets. The code that creates the monthly summary sheet has some lines that insert a blank row every 10 rows because the next day's data starts every 10 rows.

What I'm trying to do now is find the code that will insert the date into column A of the newly created blank rows. So column A in the first newly created blank line would contain 1/1/2018,The 2nd newly created blank row would have 1/2/2018 and so on.

Here is my current code, please let me know if you have any ideas for what to add to it to insert the dates in the newly created blank row. Another possible solution that I don't know how to implement would be copying the title of each worksheet to every 10th row since every worksheet is simply titled the date.

```
Sub endofmonth()
  'This sub should be run at the end of the month and will generate a monthly     summary sheet
  Dim wrk As Workbook
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Dim trg As Worksheet
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim colCount As Integer
  Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook
  For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
    If sht.Name = "Month End" Then
      MsgBox "There is a worksheet called as 'Month End'." & vbCrLf & _
             "Please remove or rename this worksheet since 'Month End' would be" & _
             "the name of the result worksheet of this process.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Error"
      Exit Sub
    End If
  Next sht
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set trg = wrk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count))
  trg.Name = "Month End"
  Set sht = wrk.Worksheets(1)
  colCount = sht.Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column
  With trg.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount)
    .Value = sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount).Value
    .Font.Bold = True
  End With
  For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
    If sht.Index = wrk.Worksheets.Count Then
      Exit For
    End If
    Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
    trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
  Next sht
  trg.Columns.AutoFit
  'This part of the code formats the Monthly Summary sheet correctly
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Month End")
    .Columns(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0).NumberFormat = "HH:MM AM/PM"
    .Columns(4).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0).NumberFormat = "00"
    .Columns(10).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0).NumberFormat = "00.00"
    .Columns(17).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    .Columns(18).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    .Columns(19).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    'This part of the code inserts a break at the end of every day on the monthly  summary sheet
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim cnt As Long
    lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    rw = 2
    cnt = 1
    Do
      If cnt = 10 Then
        Rows(rw).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        cnt = 1
        lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      Else
        cnt = cnt + 1
      End If
      rw = rw + 1
    Loop While rw <> lr

  End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How does the code know what month?  Is it always last month?  So if you pressed the button today, it would use March dates?

Comment: It would always be pressed on the last day of the month. So I would have pressed it on the 30th of march since that's the last work day of march. Also, I forgot to mention earlier that in the main page which contains the actual buttons, cell A1 is just =TODAY(). When you press a button to archive the daily report then the new sheet that is created is just named after A1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comment:

> It would always be pressed on the last day of the month. So I would
>   have pressed it on the 30th of march since that's the last work day of
>   march.

You just need to add a variable keeping track of the day, and then use that variable inside the `If cnt = 10 Then` block.

Add this variable:

```
Dim DayIndex as Date:   DayIndex = CDate(Evaluate("DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)"))
```

And then:

```
  If cnt = 10 Then
    Rows(rw).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Cells(rw, "A").Value = DayIndex
    Cells(rw, "A").NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"
    DayIndex = DayIndex + 1
    cnt = 1
    lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Else
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working but I'm wondering if the reason it's not is that there is a header row?

Comment: @Jb83 it worked when I tested it.  Header row shouldn't make a difference.  Is your column A populated?

Comment: Ah, I figured out the issue. It is working but the first row is formatted as HH:MM because except for the blanks it contains times. But I am sure I can use a format function in the code to format DayIndex as short date or something.

Comment: @Jb83 I have updated the code to include a line to set the cell format to display a date properly.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Quick follow up if anyone is still out there. I've had to add 3 additional sheets before my first one to house some data from some sql pulls but I don't want to include them on my summary sheet that this creates. How would I skip the first however many sheets?